# Create dynamic stylesheet

Tags: plone, stylesheet

I need to allow the webmaster of a plone site to change the "main color" of the site (repercuted on the docuemntFirstHeading, portletHeader, etc).
I think I can use the `base_properties.prop` file liked to a `mystylesheet.css.dtml` file.
Is there a way to modifiy programmaticaly the `base_properties` file  (which would repercute the changes in `mystylesheet.css.dtml` with a "&dtml-maincolor" declaration) ?

I'm using Plone 4.3.3

Comment: It's 100% possible I think, but I fear you must have Manager permissions to access those kind of ZMI objects.

It's probably simpler to register a new CSS that is in facts a Plone view that output a text with text/css mimetype.
This view could read a custom CSS stored in the Plone registry.

Answer (score 1):

There was a product for Plone 3 called CSSManager which provided a form to edit the base_properties. It may need some updating of imports to work in Plone 4; Plone 4's default "sunburst" theme does not use base_properties, so there probably hasn't been much motivation for that basic maintenance to happen.

Maybe you can look at its code to find out how to edit base_properties.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CSSManager

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [stylesheet in adi.slickstyle](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/adi.slickstyle/trunk/adi/slickstyle/adi_slick.css) (disclaimer: one of my humble packages), which collects and unifies all selectors setting col, bg-col and borders, so they can be set at once.

If you want to give a user access to a customizable stylesheet via a Plonesite's UI (=not ZMI), check out [adi.ttw_styles](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/adi.ttw_styles) (disclaimer: yet another one of my humble packages) it allows to use a 'page'-contenttype as the stylesource, thus you can grant edit-permission to any user you want, easily via the sharing-tab of the page.

The future: Plone 5 is said to introduce LESS based styles, to address this and make base_properties obsolete.